# Can't get Right aligned number triangle pattern giving space using setw in C++

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, iomanip

I want a right aligned number pattern using **setw** for giving spaces
either the spaces disappear when setw is less than no. of printed numbers or it makes any random pattern.
My Code is below:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include<iomanip>
 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
   int space, n,i,j,k,l,m;
   cin>>n;

   for (k = n; k <=2*n-1; k++)
   {
        cout<<setw(k);
   }
   for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
     for(j=1;j<=i;j++){
        cout<<j;
     }
     cout<<endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

The output I am getting is (n=5):

```
        1
12
123
1234
12345
```

The output I want is (n=5):

```
    1
   12
  123
 1234
12345
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `for` loop is not necessary.

`setw` sets the field length for the next field (the field following `setw`). So if the next field is an empty string, `setw(x)` will just reserve `x` characters space. Also, the value `x` should be equal to `n - i` (if no. of characters to be printed is 1, you need (5 - 1) i. e. 4 spaces)

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <iomanip>
 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
   int n, i, j;
   cin >> n;

   for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
     cout << setw(n - i) << "";
     for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        cout << j;
     }
     cout << endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: why in the 11th line you are using "" in cout?

Comment: @ShashaankKumar, I explained it already: *So if the next field is an empty string, `setw(x)` will just reserve x characters space.*